# How do I capture these variable no. of lines using regex?

Tags: regex

I've text files like this:

```
xyz
123. sometext1
233. sometext2
908. sometext3
abc
```

Thing is the no. of lines between `xyz` and `abc` can be a variable. But these follow the same specified pattern. I want to capture these lines independently. Is it possible? If it is, How?

The following regex is matching but I don't understand how to refer to the matching in replace:

```
xyz\r\n((\d{3}). (.*)\r\n)+abc
```

Comment: What do you mean by "to refer to the matching in replace"?

Comment: @claws: Which regex tool/language are you using?

Answer (score 1):

I do not know what replace mechanism you are using, however, you *should* be able to access matched groups in replace statements through the use of the dollar sign symbol (`$`) and the group number (starting from 1). So in short, `$1` will represent the `\d` segment and so on.

A problem which might exist with your regex though is this: `(\d){3}`. This will create 3 groups of 1 digit each, which I do not think is what you are after. If this is the case, simply replacing it with the following: `(\d{3})` should do the trick.

Comment: Sorry that `(\d){3}` was a typo. I fixed it. I was actually using `(\d{3})`

Answer (score 1):

Here is a perl way:

```
perl -anE 'say $1 if((/xyz/ ... /abc/) and /^(\d+)/)' in.txt
```

where in.txt is:

```
000. sometext0
xyz
123. sometext1
233. sometext2
908. sometext3
abc
456. sometext4
```

**output:**

```
123
233
908
```